# Requirements to perform a two-way factorial ANCOVA

Tags: ancova

This is a question that landed on my desk, and I don't have the requisite experience to reply.

A researcher has been asked to perform (by a journal reviewer) a two-way factorial ANCOVA on some microrarray data (a single array will be a single measurement of ~30,000 entities from a single sample in this case).

The suggestion was to use ethnicity and age as co-variables.  I understand that ANCOVA requires at least one categorical and one continuous predictor variables.

The researcher has 3 ethnic groupings in his samples - 6 of group A, 2 of group B and 1 of group C.  These samples are spread across three treatments (X, Y and Z), with 3 samples per treatment.  This means the treatments cannot be split evenly by ethnicity, group C will only appear in *one* of the treatments.

Is this sample size/grouping issue a barrier to running a two-way factorial ANCOVA?  Is there another test that might be more appropriate under the circumstances?

Answer (score 2):

A total sample size of nine is simply too small to do a two-way factorial ANCOVA or a two way-factorial ANOVA. I would have thought it's stretching things to even do a one-way ANOVA on nine observations, especially with 30,000 different outcomes. I think you need a bigger sample if you wish to make any statistical inferences.

Comment: I don't understand how small sample size, _by itself_, necessarily limits statistical inferences.  Sometimes the effect size is so huge that you only need enough samples to estimate variability and to check any model assumptions.